# Form submission in while loop result is coming only in the last row?

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <?php 

    $DatabaseServer = "localhost";
    $DatabaseUsername = "root";
    $DatabasePassword = "root";
    $DatabaseName = "demo";

    $Connection = mysqli_connect($DatabaseServer, $DatabaseUsername, $DatabasePassword, $DatabaseName);

    if ($Connection === false) {
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sqlusers = "select * from user";
    $result = mysqli_query($Connection, $sqlusers);
        echo "<form method='POST'>";
    while($rowuser = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $user = $rowuser['FirstName'];


        echo "<input type='text' name='firstName' value='$user' readonly>";
        echo "<select name='attendanceType'>";

            $sqltype = "select * from attendancetype";
            $resultaType = mysqli_query($Connection, $sqltype);
            while($rowtype = mysqli_fetch_array($resultaType)){
                echo "<option>";
                echo $rowtype['name'];
                echo "</option>";
            }

        echo "</select>";
        echo "<br>";

    }
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>";
    echo "</form>";
    ?>
```

**Users table.**

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`UserID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email`, `Password`, `City`) VALUES
(7, 'Rahul', 'Rajshekaran', 'Rahul@zzz.xxx', 'Rahul@123', 'Pune'),
(8, 'Mahesh', 'Krishna', 'Mahesh@xxx.xxx', 'Mahesh@123', 'Delhi');
```

**attendancetype table:**

```
INSERT INTO `attendancetype` (`attendanceTypeID`, `name`) VALUES
(0001, 'Present'),
(0002, 'Absent');
```

How can I inserting data into table on a single submission of form?

Comment: Append `[]` on your name values. Example: `name='firstName[]'` and `name='attendanceType[]'`. That will make them be posted as an array. Otherwise, only one will be sent.

Comment: It's not good practice to hardcode credentials in the source code. Use(for example) `.env` files instead.

Comment: @Rahul - What was the point of reverting my edits?

Comment: For the other user that had an edit pending. _Never_ change the OP's original code!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson dear i didnt revert your edit

Comment: @RahulShrivastava - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48823060/revisions - Check from the bottom (which is the original) and go up per revision.

Comment: @Magnus: Rahul's edits need to be approved by the Review Queue, and it is quite common that the delay between an edit and its approval will overwrite edits made at a similar time.

Comment: @halfer - Fair enough.

Comment: **Warning**: the accepted answer contains database calls that do not use prepared statements. If you wish to access the database safely, search for "How to avoid SQL injection in PHP" - there is plenty of material on Stack Overflow on that theme.

Comment: **Warning**: the accepted answer contains XSS vulnerabilities. It is good practice to store user input as-is in a database, and then render it safely on output. Rendering it verbatim usually means users can inject JavaScript into other user's pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code has one mistake. If you are looping form elements, you must achieve, that every input has the unique name.

```
$i = 0; 
while($rowuser = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $user = $rowuser['FirstName'];


    echo "<input type='text' name='firstName[".$i."]' value='$user' readonly>";
    echo "<select name='attendanceType[".$i."]'>";

        $sqltype = "select * from attendancetype";
        $resultaType = mysqli_query($Connection, $sqltype);
        while($rowtype = mysqli_fetch_array($resultaType)){
            echo "<option>";
            echo $rowtype['name'];
            echo "</option>";
        }

    echo "</select>";
    echo "<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

process form with:

```
<?php
mysqli_set_charset($Connection, "utf8");
foreach($_POST['firstName'] as $i => $user) {
  $sql = "insert into table set attendance_type = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection, $_POST['attendanceType'][$i])."' where user='".mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection, $user)."'";
  mysqli_query($Connection, $sql);
}
?>
```

escapeFunction is used as a refferer to the fact, that you should escape somehow (there are more ways) every input and it needs to be replaced or defined